# xcode project name and directory change/ Git cannot see old revisions

Tags: ios, xcode, git, version-control

I am in Git madness right now!

I changed the name of my xcode project by clicking on the project name in xcode and changing the name from oldproject to newproject.

That changed the name of the project everywhere except for the folder (in finder) containing the project files. My OCD kicked in and I changed the directory name where the project files reside. I then had to manually point xcode to the location of the project files (by selecting the project in xcode, opening the utilities window and updating the "Full Path"). The app still works fine.

Now comes the Git part. I checked git status in Terminal and it said that I needed to add the directory newprojectdirectory/.  I did and then did a commit. And now I can do commit and use Git as normal going forward but I can't see any of the oldprojectdirectory/ revisions.

Any thoughts?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to track history beyond rename, it's normal. 
git doesn't track history of renamed file like other files.
it is just like 'remove & add newly'

but, you can use `--follow` option

```
git log --follow rename-file
```

and you can see history beyond rename, however it works only for a file.

Answer (score 0):

use that:

```
   git mv -f [file-original] [file-renamed]
```